# javascript this reference confusion

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused about this piece of code and would appreciate some clarification. The context is just a simple dropdown menu and I'm simply adding a highlight class to link mouseover event. util.addEvent is just a simple utility I'm using for cross browser compliance.
This works.

```
var highlight = function(link){
    return function(){
    link.className="highlight";
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

```
util.addEvent(link, "mouseover", function(link){
link.className="highlight";
});
```

Also:

```
util.addEvent(link,"mouseover",function(event){
    link=event.target;
    link.className = "highlight";
});
```

this too works. When I do console.log(link) inside the second function that doesn't work, I actually get the mouse coordinates... So confused.

Comment: What does addEvent look like?  BTW, I'd recommend JQuery, they've already built the wheel for cross browser, but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because link is what will be sent in from the call from the browser on mouseover, which is the event

```
util.addEvent(link, "mouseover", function(link){
  link.className="highlight";
});
```

My guess is in your addEvent, the first parameter is what the context of this should be when the event is called, so this would work:

```
util.addEvent(link, "mouseover", function(event){
  this.className="highlight";
});
```